# Can this VBA statement be written in one line?

Tags: excel, vba

Knowing the row in an excel table, how can i reference a range of that row in one statement such as  cells(3,2) to cells(3,6) of the table in one statement?

Find Row in Table:

```
lStoreTableRow = Application.Match(Data.Cells(lDataRow, 1), Settings.Range("tblSite[Site]"), 0)
```

Currently to return 3 cells i need 3 lines:

```
BBT.Cells(lBBTRow, 11) = Application.Index(Settings.Range("tblSite[Store]"), lStoreTableRow)    'Storename
BBT.Cells(lBBTRow, 12) = Application.Index(Settings.Range("tblSite[Brand]"), lStoreTableRow)  'Brand
BBT.Cells(lBBTRow, 13) = Application.Index(Settings.Range("tblSite[Type]"), lStoreTableRow)    'Type`
```

How could i reference all three cells on the same row of the table(its not the entire row of the table)?

```
BBT.Range(BBT.Cells(lBBTRow, 11), BBT.Cells(lBBTRow, 13)) = ???
```

Comment: Why not use `ListRow.Cells`, if you know the row?

Comment: listrow is slow and buggy

Comment: I'd argue for using the `ListObject` object, instead of your `Range` calls.

Comment: ListObject is very very slow, ive tested it in the past, the time im trying to save with the above, would be lost if using ListObject to reference table for the rest of the code

Comment: Don't see a need for `Index` here either. Perhaps `Range.Cells` and `Resize` to grab 3 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also suggest following:

- Get the first source cell by `Range.Cells()`
- `Resize` it to 3 columns width
- Assign the whole `Range.Value` (needs same range sizes of source and destination)

```
BBT.Cells(lBBTRow, 11).Resize(1, 3).Value = _
    Settings.Range("tblSite[Store]").Cells(lStoreTableRow).Resize(1, 3).Value
```